# How I can do something with the extension ANGLE_instanced_arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to do any ANGLE_instanced_arrays and I was read the documentation on MDN and I did not understand anything. Well, I understood that I can make graphic 2D and 3D like : [examples](http://webglsamples.org) but for me these examples are too advanced and it's difficult to understand all the code. Can anyone help me with an example?

This part I understand of the documentation official:

> The ANGLE_instanced_arrays extension is part of the WebGL API and allows to draw the same object, or groups of similar objects multiple times, if they share the same vertex data, primitive count and type.

[here is what I read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ANGLE_instanced_arrays)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you draw without `ANGLE_instanced_arrays`? The difference between drawing with and without are

1. you call a different draw function and pass the an extra parameter of how many instances to draw. `ext.drawArraysInstancedANGLE` or `ext.drawElementsInstancedANGLE` instead of the normal `ext.drawArrays` or `ext.drawElements`
2. you add one or more attributes to your vertex shader who's values will only change once per instance drawn. In other words if you're drawing a cube the attribute's value will be the same value for every vertex while drawing the first cube, a different value while drawing the 2nd cube, a 3rd value while drawn the 3rd cube. Where as normal attributes change for each vertex these attributes only change once per cube/item.

   The most obvious attribute to add is an extra per cube position so that each cube can have a different position added to the vertex positions but you could add another attribute for a pure cube color or add matrix attributes so you can orient each cube completely independently or whatever you want.
3. For those attributes that only change once per cube you set their vertex divisor to 1 by calling `ext.vertexAttribDivisorANGLE`. The `1` means "advance the attribute every 1 instance". `0` (the default) means `advance the attribute every vertex (every iteration of the vertex shader)`.

Here's an example drawing a single quad (2 triangles, 6 vertices)

```js
const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 u_matrix;

void main() {
  gl_Position = u_matrix * position;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision mediump float;

uniform vec4 u_color;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = u_color;
}
`;

const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
const program = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);

const positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "position");

const matrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_matrix");
const colorLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_color");

const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
   // one face
    -1, -1, 
     1, -1,
    -1,  1,
    -1,  1,
     1, -1,
     1,  1,
  ],
), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
{
  const size = 2;  // 2 values per vertex
  const type = gl.FLOAT;
  const normalize = false;
  const stride = 0;
  const offset = 0;
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);
}

gl.useProgram(program);
gl.uniform4fv(colorLocation, [1, .5, .2, 1]);
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matrixLocation, false, m4.scaling([.25, .25, .25]));
const offset = 0;
const vertexCount = 6;
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, offset, vertexCount);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

and here's an example drawing 100 quads using `ANGLE_instanced_arrays`. We've added a `planeOffset` for an offset for each quad and a `planeColor` for a color for each quad.

```js
const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 planeOffset;    // per plane offset
attribute vec4 planeColor;     // per plane color
uniform mat4 u_matrix;
varying vec4 v_color;
void main() {
  mat4 translation = mat4(
    vec4(1, 0, 0, 0),
    vec4(0, 1, 0, 0),
    vec4(0, 0, 1, 0),
    vec4(planeOffset, 0, 1));
  gl_Position = u_matrix * translation * position;
  v_color = planeColor;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision mediump float;
varying vec4 v_color;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = v_color;
}
`;

function main() {
  const m4 = twgl.m4;
  const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
  const ext = gl.getExtension("ANGLE_instanced_arrays");
  if (!ext) {
    alert("need ANGLE_instanced_arrays");
    return;
  }
  
  const program = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);

  const positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "position");
  const offsetLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "planeOffset");
  const colorLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "planeColor");

  const matrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_matrix");

  const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
     // one face
      -1, -1, 
       1, -1,
      -1,  1,
      -1,  1,
       1, -1,
       1,  1,
    ],
  ), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  
  // make 100 offsets and 100 colors
  const colors = [];
  const offsets = [];
  const numInstances = 100;
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    colors.push(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1);
    offsets.push(Math.random() * 20 - 10, Math.random() * 20 - 10);
  }
  
  // put those in buffers
  const offsetBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, offsetBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(offsets), gl.STATIC_DRAW);  
  
  const colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);  

  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
  {
    const size = 2;  // 2 values per vertex
    const type = gl.FLOAT;
    const normalize = false;
    const stride = 0;
    const offset = 0;
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);
  }
  
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, offsetBuffer);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(offsetLocation);
  {
    const size = 2;  // 2 values per vertex
    const type = gl.FLOAT;
    const normalize = false;
    const stride = 0;
    const offset = 0;
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(offsetLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);
    ext.vertexAttribDivisorANGLE(offsetLocation, 1);
  }

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorLocation);
  {
    const size = 4;  // 4 values per vertex
    const type = gl.FLOAT;
    const normalize = false;
    const stride = 0;
    const offset = 0;
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);
    ext.vertexAttribDivisorANGLE(colorLocation, 1);
  }
  
  gl.useProgram(program);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matrixLocation, false, m4.scaling([.1, .1, .1]));
  const offset = 0;
  const vertexCount = 6;  
  ext.drawArraysInstancedANGLE(gl.TRIANGLES, offset, vertexCount, numInstances);
}
main();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: can you give me any example about it to I read the code ? and I understand better, I can understand your explanation but I cannot imagine in example in my mind, sorry if you think that I am a novate in js

Comment: i looking for a example basic, something so basic for I could understand deep this technology , sorry if you think that I am a novate in JS but I would like learn deep this technology.

Comment: There is no "basic" example for WebGL. WebGL is a verbose API and requires lots of knowledge. If you want to learn WebGL see [webglfunamentals.org](https://webglfundamentals.org)